# Extract multiple values from a Json response for a Post request requiring each value

Tags: json, postman, extract, response

I need to gather an array of all queueCallManagerIDs from the response and build a loop that executes an api call requiring each queueCallManagerID.

I am only able to get the first queueCallManagerID value assigned using code below:

Test:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("queueCallManagerID", jsonData.data[0].queueCallManagerID);
```

Response:

```
{
    "count": 3386,
    "status": "Complete",
    "description": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "endTime": "2024-02-23 05:07:52",
            "queueCallManagerID": "79730950",
            "mixmonFileName": "con2526-79730950.wav",
            
        },
        {
            "endTime": "2024-02-23 05:08:18",
            "queueCallManagerID": "79730957",
            "mixmonFileName": "q-con2526-us1-vp-4008-1708664701.1269429.wav",
          
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) will extract all of array data

```
const queueCallManagerIDs = jsonData.data.map(item => item.queueCallManagerID);
```

Get all array data and save into `queueCallManagerIDs` variable and extract first item and shows all of data by log()

Demo

```js
const jsonData = pm.response.json();

// Extract array of queueCallManagerID
const queueCallManagerIDs = jsonData.data.map(item => item.queueCallManagerID);

pm.environment.set('queueCallManagerIDs', JSON.stringify(queueCallManagerIDs));

console.log("all data: " + pm.environment.get("queueCallManagerIDs"));

const allData = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("queueCallManagerIDs"));
if (Array.isArray(allData) && allData.length > 0) {
    const firstData = allData[0];
    console.log("First data: " + firstData);
} else {
    console.log("No data available in the queueCallManagerIDs variable.");
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense and it worked on my end!

Comment: Good to hear, can you accept my answer, it will give me 15 points. Click up arrow in my answer.?

Comment: Sure thing. I am new, so as soon as my reputation points are added I will be allowed to vote as well.

Comment: Also, I do have a few more question's (one posted). The more I ask and answer I can reach my minimum points and then I will be able to go back and upvote.

Comment: Thanks you for you accept. it's little complicated score system. You will be vote capability in soon. What is you more question? I try help again. you can leave question in here, I will update my answer in here OR if you have another question without related this question. You can make a new question and ask to all of stack over flow guys.

Comment: I did post it, but it's referencing the next step in my process. I have to execute a POST to retrieve all associated data with the unique ID "queueCallManagerID'. Now that I have an array of queueCallManagerIDs in my queueCallManagerID environment. How do I build a loop to execute the request for each queueCallManagerID value within the environment.

I am able to manually generate the expected response, but I have less experience with loops in postman.

Here is my question with photos and examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78068578/23486160