# How do I build a loop that executes a POST for each value an array in postman

Tags: arrays, loops, post, environment-variables, postman

I have to execute a POST to retrieve all associated data with unique ID "queueCallManagerID'.
I have an array of queueCallManagerIDs in my queueCallManagerID environment. How do I build a loop to execute the request for each queueCallManagerID value within the environment.

[Api to execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9T4G.png)

[Environment with required values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhFBP.png)

I am able to manually generate the expected response, but I have less experience with loops in postman.

[Expected response but for all queueCallManagerIDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydm8Y.png)

I will have to parse through the result to organize a list of mixmonFileName.

This is the farthest I've gotten via pre-script, but it seems that it's not reading the values as an array. Error: "TypeError: queueCallManagerID.forEach is not a function"

```
// Define authorization keys
const cKey1 = '12345;
const cKey2 = '6789';
const uKey = '8765';

// Retrieve the array of queueCallManagerIDs from the environment
const queueCallManagerID = pm.environment.get('queueCallManagerID');

// Loop through each queueCallManagerID value and send a POST request
queueCallManagerID.forEach(queueCallManagerID => {
    const requestBody = {
        "cKey1": cKey1,
        "cKey2": cKey2,
        "uKey": uKey,
        "queueCallManagerID": queueCallManagerID
    };

    // Send the POST request
    pm.sendRequest({
        url: 'https://api.fathomvoice.com/V2/queues/getInteraction/',
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
        }
    }, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(res);
        console.log("queueCallManagerID:", queueCallManagerID);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd like to confirm my understanding: You want to call the ./getInteration POST API, iterating through the queueCallManagerIDs environment variable to retrieve each queueCallManagerID key/value pair using form-data until reaching the end of queueCallManagerIDs. Is this correct? Additionally, you aim to retrieve a list of mixmonFileName (an array). Am I on the right track?

Comment: We are on the right track. I corrected my environment name "queueCallManagerID". I have one queueCallManagerID variable, and it's values are ["79768757","79766443","79767811..................etc]. A post request for each value that requires 3 auth keys and queueCallManagerID will return a list of objects. I will then need to continue as you mentioned, retrieving a list of the mixmonfile name that I will have to convert to urls using a getobjetlink.  I was sure that these values represent an array, but forEach isn't working.

Comment: I updated the question to show where I am stuck at the moment. I am unsure why the values are not reading as an array. This might not be the best approach.

Comment: OK, I answered, I hope address your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman's `Run Collection` and `shift()` and `setNextRequest()` JavaScript commands will address your loop call problem.

```
pm.environment.set("queueCallManagerID", ids.shift())
postman.setNextRequest("Get Interaction A");
```

#### Note

setNextRequest's parameter "Get Interaction A" should be match collection's request name

[image]

##### Mock server for your two POST calls.

##### files structure

[image]

Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const multer = require('multer')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// for form-data
const forms = multer();
app.use(forms.array()); 

app.use(cors());
const PORT = 3000;

// Function to generate random 5-digit number
function generateRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(10000 + Math.random() * 90000);
}

// Define POST endpoint for queueCallManagerIDs Array
app.post('/V2/queues/data', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error reading file:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            
            res.json(jsonData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        }
    });
});

// Define POST endpoint for getInteraction, support form-data
app.post('/V2/queues/getInteraction', (req, res) => {
    const { cKey1, cKey2, uKey, queueCallManagerID } = req.body;
    // Form data print
    console.log(`cKey1: ${cKey1}`);
    console.log(`cKey2: ${cKey2}`);
    console.log(`uKey: ${uKey}`);
    console.log(`queueCallManagerID: ${queueCallManagerID}`);
    fs.readFile('data-result.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error reading file:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

            // Generate random number
            const randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
            jsonData.data.queueCDR.mixmonFileName = jsonData.data.queueCDR.mixmonFileName.replace(/\d{5}\.wav$/, randomNumber + '.wav');
            jsonData.data.queueCDR.queueCallManagerID = queueCallManagerID;
            res.json(jsonData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        }
    });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

##### Mocking Response Data

Save `data.json`

```json
{
    "count": 3386,
    "status": "Complete",
    "description": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "endTime": "2024-02-23 05:07:52",
            "queueCallManagerID": "79768757",
            "mixmonFileName": "con2526-797309501.wav"
            
        },
        {
            "endTime": "2024-02-23 05:08:18",
            "queueCallManagerID": "79766443",
            "mixmonFileName": "q-con2526-us1-vp-4008-1708664701.1269429.wav"
          
        },
        {
            "endTime": "2024-02-23 05:09:52",
            "queueCallManagerID": "79767811",
            "mixmonFileName": "con2526-797309502.wav"
            
        },
        {
            "endTime": "2024-02-23 05:10:18",
            "queueCallManagerID": "79761324",
            "mixmonFileName": "q-con2526-us1-vp-4008-1708664701.1234.wav"
          
        }
    ]
}
```

Save `data-result.json`

```json
{
    "status": "Complete",
    "description": "",
    "data": {
        "queueCDR": {
            "uKey": "1234",
            "queueCDRID": "79566979",
            "queueCallManagerID": "79566979",
            "queueID": "9576",
            "vbxName": "some name",
            "channel": "some channel",
            "uniqueID": "us1-vp-4055-1708356420.43542",
            "mixmonFileName": "q-con2526-us1-vp-4055-43542.wav"
        }
    }
}
```

##### Install Dependencies

```
npm install express fs multer cors
```

After install you can see those files

[image]

##### Note

If not yet install `node.js`
Try to install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download)

Then resume install dependencies

##### Running Mock Server

```
node server.js
```

[image]

##### Postman Parts

##### Import

Save as `1-1-demo.postman_collection.json`

```json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "d65b7cc6-5f59-4d45-86d7-f20439702f53",
        "name": "1-1-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Get queueCallManagerIDs",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
                            "const queueCallManagerIDs = jsonData.data.map(item => item.queueCallManagerID);\r",
                            "pm.environment.set('queueCallManagerIDs', JSON.stringify(queueCallManagerIDs));\r",
                            "console.log(\"all data: \" + pm.environment.get(\"queueCallManagerIDs\"));\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:3000/V2/queues/data",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "3000",
                    "path": [
                        "V2",
                        "queues",
                        "data"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get Interaction A",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "let ids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get(\"queueCallManagerIDs\"));\r",
                            "console.log(ids);\r",
                            "\r",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"queueCallManagerID\", ids.shift())\r",
                            "\r",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"queueCallManagerIDs\", JSON.stringify(ids));\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
                            "\r",
                            "console.log(\"queueCallManagerID: \" + pm.environment.get(\"queueCallManagerID\"));\r",
                            "console.log(\"mixmonFileName: \" + jsonData.data.queueCDR.mixmonFileName);\r",
                            "\r",
                            "let ids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get(\"queueCallManagerIDs\"));\r",
                            "if (ids.length > 0){\r",
                            "    postman.setNextRequest(\"Get Interaction A\");\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "const mixmonFileName = jsonData.data.queueCDR.mixmonFileName;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "pm.test('mixmonFileName length is greater than 0', function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(mixmonFileName.length).to.be.above(0);\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": [
                        {
                            "key": "cKey1",
                            "value": "Key 1 - top secret 6789",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "cKey2",
                            "value": "key 2 - second key 6789",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "uKey",
                            "value": "uKey - third key 8765",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "queueCallManagerID",
                            "value": "{{queueCallManagerID}}",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:3000/V2/queues/getInteraction",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "3000",
                    "path": [
                        "V2",
                        "queues",
                        "getInteraction"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Import

Select Files
[image]

Open `1-1-demo.postman_collection.json`

[image]

##### collection with two POST call

[image]

##### #1 Call 1

```
POST http://localhost:3000/V2/queues/data
```

`Tests` Tab

```js
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
const queueCallManagerIDs = jsonData.data.map(item => item.queueCallManagerID);
pm.environment.set('queueCallManagerIDs', JSON.stringify(queueCallManagerIDs));
console.log("all data: " + pm.environment.get("queueCallManagerIDs"));
```

[image]

##### #2 Call 2

```
POST http://localhost:3000/V2/queues/getInteraction
```

`Pre-request Script` Tabs

```js
let ids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("queueCallManagerIDs"));
console.log(ids);

pm.environment.set("queueCallManagerID", ids.shift())

pm.environment.set("queueCallManagerIDs", JSON.stringify(ids));
```

[image]

`Body` Tabs

```
cKey1 : Key 1 - top secret 6789
cKey2 : key 2 - second key 6789
uKey  : uKey  - third  key 8765
queueCallManagerID : {{queueCallManagerID}}
```

[image]

`Tests` Tabs

```js
const jsonData = pm.response.json();

console.log("queueCallManagerID: " + pm.environment.get("queueCallManagerID"));
console.log("mixmonFileName: " + jsonData.data.queueCDR.mixmonFileName);

let ids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("queueCallManagerIDs"));
if (ids.length > 0){
    postman.setNextRequest("Get Interaction A");
}

const mixmonFileName = jsonData.data.queueCDR.mixmonFileName;

pm.test('mixmonFileName length is greater than 0', function () {
    pm.expect(mixmonFileName.length).to.be.above(0);
});
```

[image]

##### Environment create `demo` name (any name is fine)

Two keys will be create after running collection

[image]

##### Run collection

[image]

[image]

##### Result

This POST called by number `queueCallManagerIDs` array.
`http://localhost:3000/V2/queues/getInteraction`

[image]

[image]

##### Server site

Different `queueCallManagerID` form-data input

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the details. Does Postman have a built-in feature to directly install dependencies, or will I need a Node.js environment?

Comment: Postman side not necessary to install dependencies . Postman server provide all dependencies. But mocking server needs to require node.js installation in your PC in [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download). I think before apply to your POST end-point call, try mock server and copy my Postman  setup to verify my proposal with fully understand the overall process then apply your POST call.

Comment: When attempting to run my mock server, its not located in my postman/files directory.  Will I need to export? I was using the browser version of Postman until now.

Comment: Specifically referring to node server.js

Comment: online Postman can't call localhost , so you have to install into local PC if you running mock server. I updated how to import it. And added collection file for you.

Comment: When creating the mock server, do I leave environment blank, or check "save the mock server URL as a new environment variable"?

Comment: environment should be any one pick up, like 'dev', if blank environment , the running API call will be broken.

Comment: I updated `Environment create` part in Postman side. Any name is fine, I used `demo` name.

Comment: @ThomasW, are you still figuring out to reproduce my steps?

Comment: It seems my failure is in the mock server creation. I missing something. I have node.js, but I'm struggling with the mock server piece. I've tried to watch videos, but there is still a gap. Apologies on the delay.

Comment: What is node.js problem? I can help you.

Comment: Thats not the issue. The issue is the initial step is start to finish on creating the sever.js

Comment: Two data files "data.json" and "data-result.json" are exist in same directory as "server.js" and dependency step (npm install express fs multer cors) are successes?

Comment: Where are you creating the data file?

Comment: I posted already two files in my answer. Copy it and save into file name as I mentioned.

Comment: I have the server running now. I was suck thinking the files were to be created and saved through postman somehow. I was overthinking that part. I'll proceed with the rest and keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: No, problem I hope to success my step without problem, any problem, let me know. I can help you.

Comment: I was able to replicate successfully. Thank you so much for the details, time, and patience.

Comment: I happy to hear you got it. Can you accept and up-vote for my answer?

Comment: @ThomasW, I hope you fully understand this steps and apply your real scenario. Good Luck!