# Change reused JSON body variable in Pre-request script - Postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman-pre-request-script

I have a collection of JSON POST requests for the same API. API is the same (same URL) as well as the request structure, only few values are changing within the same JSON body which will change the business scenario. What I wanted to achieve is to store a standard request in a variable and change only affected values within a pre-request script.
That has to be dynamic and reusable.

I did configure in the Collection pre-request script the following (I'll make it simple)

```
const StandardCreateReq = {
  "FullName" : "{{FUllName}}",
  "ApplicantWebGuid": `${pm.environment.get('APPWEBGUID')}`,
  "Address": "Main Street"
};
pm.environment.set("CreateRequest" , JSON.stringify(StandardCreateReq));
```

Within the request body, instead of writing the full JSON body I'm just configuring it like this:

{{CreateRequest}}

So far so good, it works and I'm able to send the request correctly.
What I would like to do is, within the pre-request script of the single request (N.B. not in the pre-request script of the collection) to be able to change few values, for instance either the address with a specific value, or an environment variable like EXISTING_APPWEBGUID instead of the one I'm using which is APPWEBGUID.

I'd need to do this for several requests and I don't want to rewrite the json body everytime and just changing values, I want only within the specific request and as a pre-request action, to be able to change only one or two values.
The idea and the difficulty it would be to retrieve the string {{CreateRequest}} and change values in it, I tried with JSON.parse but I'm not able to make it work :-(
A possible result would be to send request like following
Request 1

```
{
  "FullName" : "John Doe",
  "ApplicantWebGuid": "12345",
  "Address": "Main Street"
}
```

Request 2

```
{
  "FullName" : "Jack Brown",
  "ApplicantWebGuid": "67890",
  "Address": "Main Street"
}
```

Hope you did get my point and you can help me

Comment: Can you give us, at least three different "StandardCreateReq" examples?, it just  `ApplicantWebGuid` change OR `StandardCreateReq` change? And URL example  and which Verb call (Get or Post)

Comment: Hi @BenchVue, I did edit the question to be more clear. Same URL, same POST request structure, only some value for the same field should be changing.

Comment: 'Postman Run Collection' method can address your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman Run Collection can do repeat API call with same URL by changing Body content.

##### Mocking server

Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const multer = require('multer')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// for form-data
const forms = multer();
app.use(forms.array()); 

app.use(cors());
const PORT = 3000;

// Function to generate random 5-digit number
function generateRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(10000 + Math.random() * 90000);
}

app.post('/v1/address', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('address-data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error reading file:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            res.json(jsonData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        }
    });
});


app.post('/v1/request', (req, res) => {
    const { FullName, ApplicantWebGuid, Address } = req.body;
    // Form data print
    console.log(`FullName: ${FullName}`);
    console.log(`ApplicantWebGuid: ${ApplicantWebGuid}`);
    console.log(`Address: ${Address}`);
    res.json({
        Application: 'virtual Application',
        name: FullName,
        id: ApplicantWebGuid,
        address: Address,
        result: 'Approved'
    });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

##### Address data

The mocking server will use this address
Save as 'address-data.json'

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "FullName" : "John Doe",
            "ApplicantWebGuid": "12345",
            "Address": "Main Street"
        },
        {
            "FullName" : "Jack Brown",
            "ApplicantWebGuid": "67890",
            "Address": "Main Street"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Install server dependencies

```
npm install express multer cors
```

#### Running server

```
node server.js
```

[image]

##### API Test

Get Address
URL

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/address
```

[image]

Request Application
URL

```
POST http://localhost:3000/v1/request
```

form-data

```
FullName : John Doe
ApplicantWebGuid: 12345
Address: Main Street
```

[image]

##### Loop Test

Save `1-1-demo.postman_collection.json`

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "b0791408-a367-47c1-a96c-3b305a634c10",
        "name": "1-1-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Get Address",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
                            "const FullNames = jsonData.data.map(item => item.FullName);\r",
                            "const ApplicantWebGuids = jsonData.data.map(item => item.ApplicantWebGuid);\r",
                            "const Addresss = jsonData.data.map(item => item.Address);\r",
                            "pm.environment.set('FullNames', JSON.stringify(FullNames));\r",
                            "pm.environment.set('ApplicantWebGuids', JSON.stringify(ApplicantWebGuids));\r",
                            "pm.environment.set('Addresss', JSON.stringify(Addresss));\r",
                            "console.log(\"FullNames data: \" + pm.environment.get(\"FullNames\"));\r",
                            "console.log(\"ApplicantWebGuids data: \" + pm.environment.get(\"ApplicantWebGuids\"));\r",
                            "console.log(\"Addresss data: \" + pm.environment.get(\"Addresss\"));"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:3000/v1/address",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "3000",
                    "path": [
                        "v1",
                        "address"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Request A",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
                            "\r",
                            "console.log(\"FullName: \" + pm.environment.get(\"FullName\"));\r",
                            "\r",
                            "let FullNames = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get(\"FullNames\"));\r",
                            "if (FullNames.length > 0){\r",
                            "    postman.setNextRequest(\"Request A\");\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            "const FullName = jsonData.name;\r",
                            "\r",
                            "pm.test('FullName suhold be applicant equal', function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(FullName).to.eql(pm.environment.get(\"FullName\"));\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "let FullNames = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get(\"FullNames\"));\r",
                            "console.log(FullNames);\r",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"FullName\", FullNames.shift())\r",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"FullNames\", JSON.stringify(FullNames));\r",
                            "\r",
                            "let ApplicantWebGuids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get(\"ApplicantWebGuids\"));\r",
                            "console.log(ApplicantWebGuids);\r",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"ApplicantWebGuid\", ApplicantWebGuids.shift())\r",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"ApplicantWebGuids\", JSON.stringify(ApplicantWebGuids));\r",
                            "\r",
                            "let Addresss = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get(\"Addresss\"));\r",
                            "console.log(Addresss);\r",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"Address\", Addresss.shift())\r",
                            "pm.environment.set(\"Addresss\", JSON.stringify(Addresss));"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": [
                        {
                            "key": "FullName",
                            "value": "{{FullName}}",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ApplicantWebGuid",
                            "value": "{{ApplicantWebGuid}}",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Address",
                            "value": "{{Address}}",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:3000/v1/request",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "3000",
                    "path": [
                        "v1",
                        "request"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

##### Import this collection into Postman

[image]

[image]

[image]

##### Run collection

[image]

[image]

##### Result

Same URL API call with different two people names
And result of test logging in Console screen.

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/request
```

[image]

##### Keys

`Pre-request Scripts` Tab get people information

```
let FullNames = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("FullNames"));
console.log(FullNames);
pm.environment.set("FullName", FullNames.shift())
pm.environment.set("FullNames", JSON.stringify(FullNames));

let ApplicantWebGuids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("ApplicantWebGuids"));
console.log(ApplicantWebGuids);
pm.environment.set("ApplicantWebGuid", ApplicantWebGuids.shift())
pm.environment.set("ApplicantWebGuids", JSON.stringify(ApplicantWebGuids));

let Addresss = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("Addresss"));
console.log(Addresss);
pm.environment.set("Address", Addresss.shift())
pm.environment.set("Addresss", JSON.stringify(Addresss));
```

[image]

Body picked up one of people
[image]

`Tests` tab checking correct matched user

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();

console.log("FullName: " + pm.environment.get("FullName"));

let FullNames = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("FullNames"));
if (FullNames.length > 0){
    postman.setNextRequest("Request A");
}

const FullName = jsonData.name;

pm.test('FullName suhold be applicant equal', function () {
    pm.expect(FullName).to.eql(pm.environment.get("FullName"));
});
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for the effort and very detailed explanation, highly appreciated. I still have to look into it carefully, not sure it is explained how to get the request from variable {{CreateRequest}}, change one value in the pre-request script and run again the modified {{CreateRequest}} in the body but I see some good hints to investigate.

Comment: Thanks you, can you following my steps first, and you can figure out how to repeat API call with environment variable, then you can apply  your real scenario. If you success my steps, give me accept and up-vote.

Comment: @MorganForever, thanks you for accepting, I used `form-data` but if you `raw` of JSON in Body. I need to update server source and Postman code. let me know.

Comment: @MorganForever, this is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068578/how-do-i-build-a-loop-that-executes-a-post-for-each-value-an-array-in-postman/78071549#78071549), you can reference it.